# Proof that $f:\mathbb R\to[-1,1], f(x)=\cos x$ is surjective

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am struggling with proving that $f:\mathbb R\to[-1,1], f(x)=\cos x$ is surjective. I would have started with:

Let $y$ be in $[-1,1]$ and choose $x= \arccos y$. But then $x$ would be only in $[-1,1]$ and not in $\mathbb R$. How shall I choose $x$ in order to prove that $\cos x$ is surjective?

Comment: Do you know that the cosine function is continuous? And which definition of cosine do you work with (geometric, power series, from complex exponential, ...)?

Comment: Note that $\arccos y \in [-\pi,\pi]$, not in $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $[-\pi,\pi]\subset \mathbb R$, thus finding $x\in\mathbb [-\pi,\pi]$ s.t. $\cos x = y$ (the correct range of $\arccos$) is sufficient.
The definition of surjective asks you only to find *any* $x$ such that $f(x) = y$, it's not important if that $x$ is only found within a subset of the domain.

Comment: a thanks great !seems that I suffered from a short brainlagg.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way to prove it is to use [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Theorem): Since $f(x)=\cos x$ is continuous and $f(0)=1$ and $f(\pi)=-1$. Now, for any $y\in(-1,1)$, there exists some $x\in (0,\pi)$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f: X\to Y$ is said to be *surjective* if for each $y\in Y$, there is **some** $x\in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. You don't need to find $x$'s in all of $\mathbb{R}$. It's enough to find them on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $y \in \left[-1, 1 \right]$, let $x = \arccos y \Rightarrow  y = \cos x \Rightarrow$ $f$ is surjective.